# array push results in empty array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I am trying to store API results into an array.

The data is displayed in console, but on pushing the data into an array, the array is still empty.

Here's the code:

```
app.post('/fetchFavoriteTweets/', verifyToken, function(req, res) {

var favorites = [];
  dbConn.then( function (database) {
            var dbo = database.db("twitter_search");
            dbo.collection('users').findOne(
              { _id: ObjectId(req.userId) }, function(err, result) {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!result.hasOwnProperty('favorite_tweets')) {
                  res.status(404).json({msg:'record not found'});
                } 
                else {
                  result.favorite_tweets.forEach(function (tweet) {
                    T.get('statuses/show', {id: tweet.id}, function(err, data, response) {
                      if(!err){
                        favorites.push(data);
                        console.log(data); //this returns data
                      } else {
                        console.log(err);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                  console.log(favorites); 
                  // res.status(200).json({msg:'success', data:favorites});
                }
              });
    }).catch(function(e){console.log(e)})
});
```

Comment: if you try to access `favorites` outside the Promise , yes it's empty, because the promise is not yet fulfilled, you should pass it as a callback or async/await the promise

Comment: @darklightcode can you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @Azima - pretty much same as the answer you have below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code to get favorites by storing separately the promise and call it afterwards:

**UPDATE**

As you can see in the demo, i have 2x console.log at the bottom, the first one(**C1**) is contained in the promise `favoritesPromise ()` and the second (**C2**) is after the promise.
Synchronous actions will never wait for asynchronus actions to take place, therefore in my example **C2** will always be outputted before **C1**, even if console.log(1 ... ) is before console.log(2 ... ), they'll appear reversed in the console.

In the promise i added a `setTimeout` of 1ms to mock a request, it was all it took to achieve the current output. Another thing you can test is removing the `setTimeout` then output will change a bit, your promise becomes synchronus until it reaches `resolve(favorites)`, that means `favorites` has all the data by now, but when `resolve` takes place, it becomes async, and in your console you will still see **C2** first (but now with data) and **C1** second.

In my earlier answer i tried to implement this reasoning to your code.
**Keep it async folks!**

```js
var favorites = [];

var favoritesPromise = () => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log('Retrieving data from the internet.');

    // This timeout mocks your request to anything that is async or promie
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log('Request done')

      let resultFavorite_tweets = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'a dog'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'a cat'
      }];

      resultFavorite_tweets.forEach(item => {

        favorites.push(item.name);

      })

      resolve(favorites);

      // if you have an error use
      // reject(err)

    }, 1);


  });

}

favoritesPromise().then(favList => {
  console.log(1, 'this will always contain data from the internet, but will always be last', favList);
})

console.log(2, 'this will be empty (unless you remove setTimeout), but will always be first', favorites);
```

```
 app.post('/fetchFavoriteTweets/', verifyToken, function(req, res) {


  const favoritesPromise = () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var favorites = [];
      dbConn.then(function(database) {
        var dbo = database.db("twitter_search");
        dbo.collection('users').findOne({
          _id: ObjectId(req.userId)
        }, function(err, result) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          if (!result.hasOwnProperty('favorite_tweets')) {
            res.status(404).json({
              msg: 'record not found'
            });
          } else {
            result.favorite_tweets.forEach(function(tweet) {
              T.get('statuses/show', {
                id: tweet.id
              }, function(err, data, response) {
                if (!err) {

                  favorites.push(data);
                  console.log(data); //this returns data

                } else {

                  console.log(err);
                  reject(err);

                }

              });

              resolve(data);

            });
            console.log(favorites);
            // res.status(200).json({msg:'success', data:favorites});
          }
        });
      }).catch(function(e) {
        reject(e)
      })

    });

  }


  // Here you call the promise to retrieve "favorites"
  favoritesPromise().then(favoritesList => {

    console.log('your favorites array', favoritesList)

  })


})
```

Comment: I'm getting following error now:
`E:\twitter_search_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132`
      `throw err;`
      `^`

`ReferenceError: data is not defined`
    `at E:\twitter_search_backend\app.js:243:23`
    `at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`

Comment: @Azima try and comment `reject(err)` from the `T.get('statuses/show')` callback, thus the error is self-explanatory ( are you getting a response in `data`, does it show up in console.log ? )

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're defining the `favorites` array within the scope of the function callback. Try putting `var favorites = [];` above you `app.post()` call instead.

Also, keep in mind that it will only have a value after the callback is complete, so any synchronous code later down the line will only see the empty array value.

Answer (score 1):

Try next code

```
app.post('/fetchFavoriteTweets/', verifyToken, function (req, res) {
  var favorites = [];
  dbConn.then(function (database) {
    var dbo = database.db("twitter_search");
    dbo.collection('users').findOne(
      { _id: ObjectId(req.userId) }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty('favorite_tweets')) {
          res.status(404).json({ msg: 'record not found' });
        }
        else {
          // Counter
          let count = result.favorite_tweets.length;
          result.favorite_tweets.forEach(function (tweet) {
            T.get('statuses/show', { id: tweet.id }, function (err, data, response) {
              // Decrease count
              count -= 1;
              if (!err) {
                favorites.push(data);
                // Check if count is zero
                if (count === 0) {
                  console.log(favorites);
                  res.status(200).json({msg:'success', data:favorites});        
                }
              } else {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
  }).catch(function (e) { console.log(e) })
});
```